# Strange error language during web scraping with vba

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, web-scraping

I, everybody.
I'm submitting you a strange problem that occurs sometimes.
I wrote a VBA code to scrape data's from a website that use English.
So, as I need to compare the extracted data's with some others I want to handle, I'm always expecting them in English, so I'll be able to find them in an ACCESS table. However, it happens that unexpectedly the data's are in German, nullifying my research. I have analyzed the WEB page, and the HTML code is always in English, yet sometimes the extraction is in German.

In fact, MS Windows 10 I've installed is the German version, but this should not cause problems, because I expect that the language that I read on the page is (always) the one I extract.
The browser I'm referring for the scraping is Mozilla Firefox.

The code is the following (on the peculiar part):

```
sAPPOGGIO = UrlWEB(1)
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", sAPPOGGIO, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    .send
     Do While .ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Pausa (2)
    Loop
    sHTM = .responseText
End With
'assegnazione dell pagina estratta
Set ohtm = New HTMLDocument
ohtm.body.innerHTML = sHTM
```

Then, working inside the object 'ohtm', sometimes the extraction finds terms in German, when the most part of times they are in English.

Is there someone who cold explain me what's happening?

Comment: Something is different between the request headers when you're using Firefox vs. when you send a request via xmlhttp.  You can use (eg) Fiddler to examine the differences.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: This one, for example: [link]https://musicbrainz.org/release/a993829f-ba8d-4e19-ae19-406c3d7c71f1